# Error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'email.FeedParser'

Tags: node.js, python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am getting Error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'email.FeedParser' when trying to import the following Python libraries:

```py
from googleapiclient import discovery
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file, client, tools
```

I am using Python 2.7. These imports are inside Google API Python scripts that work fine when being called from the terminal. However, calling them from a nodejs application causes this error to appear.

I have followed the steps numbered in:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#vendoring to add the libraries using the lib folder

This solved the initial problem with the googleapiclient but it doesn't seem to work for the httplib2 library.

Any idea on what I could be missing?

This is the nodejs code that calls the script:

```
app.post('/newProject', (req, res) => {
  //Get date from form

  var nombre = req.body.nombre;

  var PythonShell = require('python-shell');
  var options = {
    args: [nombre], // pass arguments to the script here
  };

  //you can use error handling to see if there are any errors
  ps.PythonShell.run('./createFolder.py', options, function (err, results) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('results: %j', results);
  });
  //your code

  //send result
  res.send(`Full asda is:${nombre}.`)

});
```

This is the complete error:

> Error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'email.FeedParser'
>       at PythonShell.parseError (/Users/pol/Documents/sf/lego/legoUI/node_modules/python-shell/index.js:246:21)
>       at terminateIfNeeded (/Users/pol/Documents/sf/lego/legoUI/node_modules/python-shell/index.js:129:32)
>       at ChildProcess. (/Users/pol/Documents/sf/lego/legoUI/node_modules/python-shell/index.js:121:13)
>       at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
>       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:12)
>       ----- Python Traceback -----
>       File "createFolder.py", line 4, in 
>         import createFolderV01
>       File "/Users/pol/Documents/sf/lego/legoUI/createFolderV01.py", line 3, in 
>         from googleapiclient import discovery
>       File "/Users/pol/Documents/sf/lego/legoUI/lib/googleapiclient/discovery.py", line 52, in 
>         import httplib2
>       File "/Users/pol/Documents/sf/lego/legoUI/lib/httplib2/**init**.py", line 28, in 
>         import email.FeedParser

Edit: Solved it. As it turns out, you can specify which python interpreter nodejs will call as a option parameter.

Comment: did you do a `npm i`? or maybe do one `npm i python-shell`

Comment: Hello! Yes, I did. And I am able to execute other scripts just fine. The error seems to be on the imports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. The problem was that node was trying to execute the script using Python 3 and the google libraries are all done using python 2.7. To force it to use Python 2, I added

```
var options = {
        pythonPath: '/usr/bin/python2.7',
        args: [nombre], // pass arguments to the script here
};
```

the pythonPath to the options for executing the script.

Answer (score 0):

If this problem happens while running from command line. Setting CLOUDSDK_PYTHON to use python2 worked for me.

`export CLOUDSDK_PYTHON=python2`